# Redux - Map dispatch to prop -> got undefined when call action

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to build infinitive scroll in react using React / react-redux. Here is my container component :

```
    import React from "react";
    import {SingleArticleContainer} from "./singleArticleContainer";
    import {connect} from "react-redux";

    export class ArticleList extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount(){
            window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
        }
        componentWillUnmount() {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
        }

        handleScroll(event){
            let scrollTop = event.srcElement.body.scrollTop;
            let viewHeight=window.innerHeight;
            let elemtScrollHeight=event.srcElement.body.scrollHeight;
            if((elemtScrollHeight-scrollTop-viewHeight)<=20){
               //load more article from server.
                   this.props.loadMoreArticles(); <--- got error because this.props is undefined
//HOW CAN I MAKE CALL HERE?
            }

        }

        render(){
                return <div>
                       {this.props.articles.map(()=>
                        <SingleArticleContainer/>
                          )} 
                       </div>
               }
    }

const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
     return {
            articles:state.articles
            };
}

const mapDisptachToProps=(dispatch)=>{
      return {
              loadMoreArticles:()=>{
               dispatch(loadArticles());
                }
             }                         
      }
```

I also create the action creator for the action `loadArticles` 
my action creator :

```
export function loadArticles(){
     return {
            type:"LOAD_ARTICLES"
           };
}
```

QUESTION: How do I call `loadMoreArticles` inside `handleScroll` function? As I understand that the `loadMoreArticles` is now a property of component.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to bind the function because `this` won't refer to your component in `handleScroll`, but to `window` instead. This should work:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.scrollEvent = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollEvent);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollEvent);
}
```

Comment: change as your suggest but still don't work. Please note that the `props` of component is undefined in `handleScroll` function. So you answer is irrelevant. Thank for your answer

Comment: If you write `console.log(this)` in your `handleScroll` function you'll see that `this` is referring to your window object. I made a typo in my code, but nabn updated it for me, hope this now works.

Comment: yes. You were right about the window object. But anyway, I cannot call `loadMoreArticles` inside handleScroll function. it got `undefined`. Any idea ?

Comment: Try if the updated code above works, if it doesn't, try this: `window.addEventListener('scroll', () => this.handleScroll());`. That should definitely work, but you won't be able to remove the event afterwards (that's why I used the `bind` function to store the event reference)

Comment: thanks Robert. I updated code but unfortunately still cannot call `loadMoreArticles` inside `handleScroll` function.

Answer (score 0):

`this.props` is undefined because you must bind the method to access `this` with ES6 syntax, there is no autobinding. You can do it, for example, on the constructor with `this.handleScroll= this.handleScroll.bind(this)`.

Comment: Changed as your suggestion.  But I still can not make call to `loadMoreArticles` inside `handleScroll`

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you didn't wrap your component with **connect** because I've seen this line:

```
export class ArticleList extends React.Component{
```

and you have reminded about **container component** and I guess that you are using react-redux.

Please modify as bellow and tell us the result (Focus on last line):

```
import React from "react";
import {SingleArticleContainer} from "./singleArticleContainer";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

class ArticleList extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount(){
            window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
        }
        componentWillUnmount() {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
        }

        handleScroll(event){
            let scrollTop = event.srcElement.body.scrollTop;
            let viewHeight=window.innerHeight;
            let elemtScrollHeight=event.srcElement.body.scrollHeight;
            if((elemtScrollHeight-scrollTop-viewHeight)<=20){
               //load more article from server.
                   this.props.loadMoreArticles(); <--- got error because this.props is undefined
//HOW CAN I MAKE CALL HERE?
            }

        }

        render(){
                return <div>
                       {this.props.articles.map(()=>
                        <SingleArticleContainer/>
                          )} 
                       </div>
               }
    }

const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
     return {
            articles:state.articles
            };
}

const mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=>{
      return {
              loadMoreArticles:()=>{
               dispatch(loadArticles());
                }
             }                         
      }
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ArticleList)
```

For more details, please check Redux documentation:
http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#presentational-and-container-components

Comment: Cảm ơn Hiếu.  Ofcourse I did wrap it with `connect` and use the container component but it didn't work.  Sorry for missing the connect code here.

Comment: are you sure? Can you share your code with the missing connect code?